# How to save user specific settings with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to save user-specific settings for my web application, but the amount of information out there is overwhelming me and I'm not sure what the standard way to do this is. It's a Google Maps application and the types of settings I am talking about are things like current map center, zoom level, etc so that when a user exits the application and returns it appears the same way as when they left it.

This is an MVC5 app. We are using Entity Framework database-first for storage, and the Identity API for user logins. My Googling shows that this is built on code-first, so I'm not sure what that means for me. I see a lot of information about the User Profiles API and cookies, but there is so much varying info that I'm not sure what is current or if there is some standard way to do this. I could just add tables to my database and stick these settings in there, but is there some more correct way to accomplish this? It seems like they should tie in to the Identity database somehow since it's already there.

Comment: I think this is likely to be too opinion based. personally, I like to keep my user identity stuff separate from my application stuff. I use claims to store the key for an application user table, then build a DB schema off that. I don't like the idea of having to change the auth schema for application changes.

Comment: So you would just make a separate table in the application's database and store the user ID from the identity stuff there along with the settings?

Comment: no, i have my own user tables, with (for example) an int id field. I add a claim to the UserClaims table in the identity tables with a value that is the int ID. When a user logs in, I can check the claims, read the value and look up other stuff from that.

Comment: Although it is my opinion, I generally use a table that has the schema of `userId | key | value` to store settings like these. It makes it easy to get all the settings, feed them into a dictionary and then push them client-side.